# Eclipse on Mac 10.8 - Installed 1.7.0 JRE / JDK, but Eclipse won't launch

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

- Installed Java SE 1.7.0u10 from Oracle w/ their installer package
- Downloaded and unpacked Eclipse Juno (4.2.1)
- Double click Eclipse purple icon and get OS X alert prompt with error message:

> To open "Eclipse," you need a Java SE 6 runtime. Would you like to
>   install one now?

- (in terminal) `which java` - `/usr/bin/java`
- `ls -l /usr/bin/java` - `/usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`
- (in Finder) Double click eclipse alias (included when unpacked download) - Terminal launches, `/Applications/Eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse ; exit ;` and Exclipse launches without OS X alert prompt.

I've tried modifying the Eclipse app bundle plist to point the -vm key to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.frameworks/Versions/Current/Commands/java, but I feel like I probably shouldn't have to do this.`

I'd like to know how to get Eclipse to launch by just double clicking on the Application package. It's such a small thing to bug me... :o)

Comment: It says you need Java 6. Java 7 does not mean Java 6 plus new features

Comment: @AlexYan I'm not sure I understand. I don't have Java 6 installed on my system, however Eclipse will run when executed from the command line `/Applications/Eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse`. This would indicate to me that I am not required to install both Java 6 and Java 7. Can you please clarify?

Comment: What I meant was Java 6 and 7 are different. Having JRE7 does not necessarily mean all Java programs written in Java below version 7 will run. One of my school projects last year ran differently in JRE7 than it did in JRE6. And Eclipse might be strict in checking this kind of thing, I'm not sure

Comment: Oh, I also found this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374791 . There seems to be a bug in Eclipse that results in the problem you're experiencing. There is a patch included with that bug report that might solve your problems, but you'll have to apply it yourself. I'm not sure how you'd go about doing that though

Comment: Make sure you are using 64bit Eclipse. Had no luck running 32bit one on 1.7 jvm with any options.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20609249/1096742 , this question is already answered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Kepler for OS X Mavericks request Java SE 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563766/eclipse-kepler-for-os-x-mavericks-request-java-se-6)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer over on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58841)

It's an ugly hack, but works perfectly.

Comment: @Hisham's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19580605/166339) is better than the ugly hack.

Comment: I don't disagree that it is a technically superior way to launch Eclipse, but it does not answer my original question: `I'd like to know how to get Eclipse to launch by just double clicking on the Application package.`

Comment: Are you willing to add Eclipse to your dock? If so, you can get it down to a single click with @Hisham's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19580605/166339). Just launch Eclipse once from the command line, and then drag it at least one space over to dock it. From that point on, simply click on the docked Eclipse item. (You may have to allow execution of unsigned programs, especially if you're running Mavericks where it's not the default setting).

Comment: I think that the solution given by @jkwuc89 is cleaner (and without side effects) http://stackoverflow.com/a/10374886/778891

Answer (score 11):

The best answer is to fix the Java 7 installation as shown here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19594116

Simple to do and I have confirmed it works on Mavericks. With this fix, you can launch your app from the launchpad as usual. If you upgrade your JDK, you will have to reapply the fix to the new installation.

Answer (score 9):

I had JDK 7 installed and I solved this issue for eclipse Kepler by running eclipse from the terminal instead of the finder.

```
./eclipse
```

Just thought to share.

**Update 1**

For the sake of completeness, if you want to run it from Finder as well, you can wrap the ./eclipse command into a .command file and run it from Finder (so that you don't have to open a terminal)

The following lines should do the job (don't forget to replace "your-full-eclipse-path" with the eclipse path on your machine)

```
#!/bin/sh
/your-full-eclipse-path/eclipse
```

After that, give execute permission to the eclipse.command file you just created

```
chmod +x eclipse.command
```

Comment: +1 This is the best answer. Much better than adding symlinks or installing Java 6. It just works.

Comment: much easier than other solutions

Comment: Did not work for me.  When I double-click on the shell I created I get the following in Terminal:

Unable to find any JVMs matching architecture "x86_64".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
No Java runtime present, requesting install.

I have confirmed that I have JRE 7 installed.

Comment: Make sure java is installed properly; i.e. what happens when you open a terminal and run "java"?

Answer (score 4):

posted on this page: [Mountain Lion with Java 7 only](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58203/mountain-lion-with-java-7-only/58841#58841)

To trick OS X to accept Java 7 instead of proposing to install Java 6 a simple symlink is enough:

> sudo mkdir /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
>
> sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk

Most Java Programs will run with this little hack without the need to install Java 6. OS X's Java Preferences (and maybe some others) will not as it seems to explicitly check the version of the JVM when it is started.

script above can fix my problem.

Comment: Sorry about the previous comment and downvote, please disregard.

Answer (score 3):

Hoping you are using 64-bit of Java SE 1.7.0 and so advising the following.

1. go to Eclipse->Preferences...->Java->Installed JREs
2. click Add...
3. Select Standard VM
4. paste `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home` into **JRE home**
5. Change the JRE name to something useful like Java SE 7
6. Click Finish
7. Check the check-box next to your newly created JRE.

You would need a restart.

Comment: No change. I'm still receiving the same message from OS X. Also, that JRE location already shows up in in the installed JREs window (just listed as `(MacOS X Default)`)

Answer (score 3):

Can you imagine that? You have to install a JDK 1.6 to get eclipse ran properly, even if you already have jdk 1.7 installed, and set the JAVA_HOME properly.

To resolve your issue, you just need to download the jdk1.6 from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US, and install it, later you will be able to run eclipse, and you can set the JAVA_HOME to JDK1.7, and you will be able to find the JDK1.7 from eclipse "Preferences".

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, the Eclipse team seems to have worked around it by replacing their dlopen()-based method with a CFBundleCreate()-based one: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=411361

In case anybody has the same problem in their code that launches Java and does not want to resort to Apple-only APIs, I found an easier work-around: before dlopen()ing $JRE_HOME/lib/server/libjvm.dylib, make sure to open dlopen() $JRE_HOME/lib/jli/libjli.dylib. Then it won't ask to install Java 6.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. libjli.dylib also has the _JNI_* functions and it seems I can use the pointers to those without opening libjvm.dylib at all. Will have to test this.

Comment: Yes, works using libjli.dylib only. (Thought at first it didn't but that was because of an error in the code)

Answer (score 2):

All these hacks does not work on mac Mavericks,
But a simple and efficient solution is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563766/eclipse-kepler-for-os-x-mavericks-request-java-se-6) 
it worked with me like a charm.

**Note:** a drawback of this solution is when you check your java version using "java -version" command, it will read Java 1.6

Answer (score 2):

open `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdkXXXXX.jdk/Contents/Info.plist`

settting(`<string>BundledApp</string>` is usefull!):

```
<key>JVMCapabilities</key>
<array>
　　<string>JNI</string>
　　<string>BundledApp</string>
　　<string>WebStart</string>
　　<string>Applets</string>
　　<string>CommandLine</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same message when setting up a new mac and trying to run eclipse 4.2.2 with only Java SE 7 installed (as part of JDK 7u17).

In order to be able to successfully launch Eclipse I had to let OSX download and install Apple's Java SE 6 runtime first before installing the latest JDK.

After installing the JDK, the command `java -version` correctly shows:

```
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

Trying to solve the problem the other way around didn't work -- i.e. installing JDK 7u17 first before installing Java SE 6 as suggested in the message.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly same problem some days ago and I solved it today. Just installed this http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572

And after that, when I opened the eclipse the OSX installed some java update and opening eclipse by Eclipse.app started working.

Hope it works with you too.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to install Java 6 JDK only (no Java 7 JDK/JRE, no Java 6 JRE only), install the Apple OSX Java DMG (at time of writing, this was http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/java_for_os_x_2013003_developer_package/java_for_os_x_2013003_dp__11m4406.dmg).

You still won't be able to start Eclipse. Make a directory *JavaVirtualMachines* under */System/Library/Java*. And then make an Alias of the java version folder at */Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines* and rename the alias *1.6.0.jdk* and copy that alias to */System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/*

After finished, you will have an Alias at */System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk* that points to the Java install directory at */Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_XX-XXX-XXX.jdk*

Answer (score 0):

1. Install latest JDK from Sun, it installs into `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`, e.g. `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk`
2. `sudo mkdir /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`
3. `sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/ /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk`

========= this trick used to work on Mountain Lion, but not on Maverick 10.9 somehow ============

Tried this again on Maverick, it does not work anymore. I also tried to change eclipse app plist and eclipse.ini (by adding -vm  or ), does not work either.

Some people suggested that this is caused by Eclipse binary prepared using Apple 1.6 appbundler instead of Oracle java7 appbundler: [Application is using Java 6 from Apple instead of Java 7 from Oracle on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806709/application-is-using-java-6-from-apple-instead-of-java-7-from-oracle-on-mac-os-x/15271448#15271448)

For now, please just type the eclipse from command line, which works fine with JAVA_HOME set to Java 7 (/usr/libexec/java_home command will tell you)

Comment: This seems rather dangerous...linking between versions is likely to have unintended consequences.  What is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 0):

## How to Make Eclipse Run on OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Attempting to launch various Eclipse versions after the Mavericks upgrade pops up a dialog with this message:

> To open "Eclipse.app" you need a Java SE 6 runtime. Would you like to install one now?

[image]

It turns out that Java 7 is disabled by default in OS X 10.9.
This is easily verified as follows:

```
$ java --version
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

**The solution** is to install the latest supported Java version from Apple support: [Java for OS X 2013-005](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) (http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572)
As of 10/15/13 this would be Java SE 6 1.6.0_65.
Post Date: Oct 15, 2013
File Size: 63.98 MB

After the install, Eclipse will run as expected from the Dock, the Finder, or the Terminal without any tricks, hacks, or work-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to run Eclipse itself with Java 7. As I have a couple of plugins that do not work without it. For me neither solution worked for 10.9, but I found a workaround. The main idea is that you start eclipse with java -jar **launcher**.jar and provide a couple of magic properties and then it starts. This guy provided the command line script in comments that works for me:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=411361#c25

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem (Mac OS X 10.9.2, Java 1.7.0_53b13, Eclipse Kepler). The workaround was quite easy:

1. Find the executable in Finder (CMD+Click on Eclipse's icon in the Dock)
2. Remove the icon from the Dock
3. CTRL+Click on the executable in Finder
4. ALT+Open (to allow the execution of a non-signed application)
5. Eclipse opens normally and without any problem
6. Re-dragged the program onto the Dock

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found that I did not have JDK installed on my Mac. Once I did that, Eclipse starts normally.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

First of all ; JDK(java development Kit) and JRE(Java Runtime Environment) are different things. It was confused by people

In order to install eclipse yo should install latest JDK . So

1. Visit
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
2. Download suitable version for your mac
3. You can check your version now ; it won't be 1.6 anymore
4. Try to install eclipse again , see it works.

Good luck!..