# Clicking on Eclipse Icon in Launchpad (Mac) doesn't launch it

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm new to Mac OS and I would like you to help me a bit with Eclipse Kepler 4.3 IDE

I drag the eclipse folder after having uncompressed it inside of the Applications folder. The icon appears in the Launchpad but when I click on it, nothing happens.

I had removed the Java v 1.6 that Eclipse needed at the first installation because I had already installed Java v 1.7 (JDK). At the second installation, it didn't ask for anything in Java but the icon still doesn't work.

The only way I can launch Eclipse is by clicking on the eclipse alias in the eclipse folder.

Do you know how to help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you uninstalled Java 6. When you installed Eclipse, the `.app` file was configured to run on Java 6, and when that is gone, it won't work. The solution is to reinstall Eclipse.

Comment: Yes maybe but can you explain to me how to do it ? 

Because between first and second installation, I drag the Eclipse Folder in the trash to "uninstall it" (maybe it's the wrong way to do that) and I download it again to put the folder inside of the Applications Folder. Is that exact ?

Comment: how did you remove java 6?

Comment: I went to the /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines and delete the 1.6.0.jdk folder.

Comment: YOU DID SOMETHING VERY BAD!!!!!! YOU MAY HAVE TO REINSTALL MAC OS X!!!!!! I AM NOT KIDDING!!!!!!

Comment: Because I didn't know why Eclipse need Java 1.6.0 and not Java 1.7.0 which was already installed in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines and which looks like to be the new path for JVM :(

Are you sure that I must reinstall ?

Comment: well, first, open the Console, a program found in /Applications/Utilities/, then try to run eclipse and see if more messages appear

Comment: Yes when I click on Eclipse Icon I get:
 18.01.14 19:05:08.937 Dock[166]: JLRequestRuntimeInstall: CFMessagePortSendRequest: error -1

Comment: So I will loose the few data that I have on my Mac no ? I don't have so much because I started to work on it for a week only ;)

Comment: you know, you have just one other option

Comment: Or maybe I can try this thing: https://discussions.apple.com/message/15246413#15246413 -> what do you think ?

Comment: i'll check that solution

Comment: you have just one other option I can think of

Comment: have you emptied the trash?

Comment: just don't delete Java like that again

Comment: Thing I don't know, it's that when I do: java -version I get the following: java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: the eclipse .app is configured to use java 6, and it won't use the java 7 you installed

Comment: I was following the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105575/eclipse-on-mac-10-8-installed-1-7-0-jre-jdk-but-eclipse-wont-launch?rq=1

But it's true I shouldn't have to remove the Java 1.6.0 folder... I will try something and come again with some news ! Thanks tbodt for your help