# Mavericks and JVM Alert

Tags: eclipse, macos, osx-mavericks

I just finished installing Mavericks (OS X 10.9) on my macbook.

Eclipse fails to open with the following error message.

[image: Eclipse Alert]

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352715/how-do-i-run-eclipse-using-oracles-new-1-7-jdk-for-the-mac

Comment: Some comments on other forums suggest reinstalling the JDK may fix this.

Comment: That link worked for me. Thanks.