# OSX 10.9 Mavericks and Eclipse Kepler (4.3.2) or M6 Eclipse Luna (4.4)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, oracle

How to get Eclipse running on OSX 10.9? I have tried some of the solutions mentioned in this thread to no avail: [How do I run Eclipse using Oracle's new 1.7 JDK for the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352715/how-do-i-run-eclipse-using-oracles-new-1-7-jdk-for-the-mac)

- editing **eclipse.ini**, adding in

`vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java` just before the `-vmargs`

- editing the **Info.plist** and adding the full path to the Oracle SDK, checked if syntax was correct by double clicking and succesfully opening it and verified that the path was correct.
- adding 4 capabilities to the JDK:

  ```
              <string>CommandLine</string>
              <string>JNI</string>
              <string>BundledApp</string>
              <string>WebStart</string>
              <string>Applets</string>
  ```
- The accepted solution, as far as running the custom shell script, to no avail:
  shell script contents (correct SDK / Launcher paths):
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/5we8kw3m3aeln0o/Screenshot%202014-03-29%2000.59.10.png
  the awesome result of.... nothing:
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8uz7043yh2h42n/Screenshot%202014-03-29%2000.59.04.png

Similar question to this thread: [Mavericks and JVM Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639587/mavericks-and-jvm-alert)

I have the Oracle JDK 1.7:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqe6pih8wiwzygk/Screenshot%202014-03-29%2000.16.52.png

It is, apparently, the only Java SDK installation:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ijf31d957u0qujy/Screenshot%202014-03-29%2000.17.14.png

I can run java and javac in the Terminal, have $JAVA_HOME set also:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzt2oaelkz1vq4o/Screenshot%202014-03-29%2000.21.09.png

This is the error i am getting:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sfv51e5s7m8lhi9/Screenshot%202014-03-29%2000.17.38.png

I am on a Macbook Pro mid 2010 model running Mavericks 10.9.2 and trying to get the mentioned Eclipse versions running, which somehow is being made practically impossible.
How to unfrak this clusterfrak?

Comment: The error message is pointing to an openJDK install not the Oracle install. The `eclipse.ini` entry must have `-vm` on a separate line from the path.

Comment: Arch, i did not know that was another JDK even. thanks, @greg-449

Comment: I downloaded the Oracle JAVA JDK 8, Eclipse Luna and it works out of the box. Please create an answer, so i can accept it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pointing to an openJDK install not the Oracle install.

The eclipse.ini entry must have -vm on a separate line from the path

```
-vm 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

although if the correct Java is the default it should not be necessary.