# Running Eclipse on Mac - JVM Version 1.7 or greater is required

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, jvm, osx-mavericks

I downloaded Eclipse (specifically that for C/C++ Programming) for Mac, running OSX Mavericks. When I try to start Eclipse, it gives me this message: "Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version 1.7 or greater is required", and it doesn't open. I installed Java version 7, but nothing changed. I don't know how else to update the JVM (I don't know much about Java in general).

I downloaded the 64-bit version for my MacBook Air, if that matters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run Eclipse using Oracle's new 1.7 JDK for the Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352715/how-do-i-run-eclipse-using-oracles-new-1-7-jdk-for-the-mac)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply Install the JDK 7 or JDK 8, and not just the latest JRE.

Comment: Here's the download page for v8: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: I had this problem on my MacOS 10.13.2 High Sierra desktop. I followed wloescher's link above to install the JDK, then re-ran the Eclispe installer. The installer worked for me, simply, with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Run `whereis java` in a Terminal. It will normally display something like `/usr/bin/java`.

Now run `java -version`. It shows you 'java version 1.6.0_65' or something approaching. This is because Java 7 does not replace Java 6. Java 7 is installed as an Internet Plug-in and can be found in `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`.

What you need to do is to symlink `/usr/bin/java` to `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`.

Restart Eclipse, or reboot your computer (I don't know how Eclipse manages this), and it should do the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

I went to [oracle downloads](http://oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/) and the scrolled one of the several Mac osX links and downloaded jdk-8u73-nb-8_1-macosx-x64.dmg from oracle and that fixed the problem. I don't know why updating java doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

add this script into 'eclipse.ini' at the top
***'/Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/contents/Home/bin'***

Answer (score 0):

Trying to install eclipse, I installed java version 1.6.0_65 as it requested yet still was blocked from finishing the Eclipse install with the error that I needed 1.7 JVM or higher - not true, installing higher didn't work either. I tried installing jdk-8u101-macosx-x64.dmg and that didn't work. So, I tried JDK 7 as advised, sorry no good.

So, to get the Eclipse installer to run with out that java error I had to edit the Info.plist inside the Eclipse Installer. Right click the Eclipse installer and show package contents, then open info.plist in textEdit.app

(Note: So after several tries editing this plist and following methods mentioned elsewhere nothing worked, I found that you have to use the symlink or java alias because java is installed differently now a days as an internet plugin.)

Where you want to make an edit (You should probably Backup the original or you can download it again), under `<key>Eclipse</key>`, then `<array>`, delete out what's there and add `<string>-vm</string>` and this string underneath; `<string>/usr/bin/java</string>`

Here is what mine looks like.

```
<key>Eclipse</key>
<array>
<string>-vm</string>
<string>/usr/bin/java</string>
<string>-keyring</string>
<string>~/.eclipse_keyring</string>
<string>-showlocation</string>
</array>
```

Then save and try running your eclipse installer; this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just running the below command from there terminal worked for me.

## brew cask install java

It updated my idk with 1.8, and after that eclipse opens successfully.