# Cannot access the roboVM settings under preferences in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, robovm

I just installed the RoboVM plugin in Eclipse and am trying to access the settings from preferences, but I am getting this error:

```
Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.robovm.eclipse.ui (879).
```

I saw that it may have something to do with not having JDK 7 installed, but I have made sure that JDK 7 is enabled on my system. Here Is the output for JAVA_HOME:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and here is the Java version

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Am I missing something?

Note: I am running this on a mac with mavericks.

Edit: Here is the stack trace:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:580)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:311)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:386)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:568)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:294)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:289)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceNode.createPage(WorkbenchPreferenceNode.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1372)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.createPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:385)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1259)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:699)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9$1.run(PreferenceDialog.java:730)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:725)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:876)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:178)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:873)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1217)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1243)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:259)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1$2.run(OpenStrategy.java:440)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3983)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:221)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.ShowPreferencePageHandler.execute(ShowPreferencePageHandler.java:59)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:196)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.cocoa.CocoaUIHandler.runCommand(CocoaUIHandler.java:715)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.cocoa.CocoaUIHandler.access$6(CocoaUIHandler.java:703)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.cocoa.CocoaUIHandler$8.widgetSelected(CocoaUIHandler.java:568)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4188)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4031)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3658)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/robovm/compiler/log/Logger : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:285)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:632)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:588)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:540)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:527)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:311)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:386)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2446)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2756)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:328)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
... 93 more
```

and here is the session data:

```
java.version=1.6.0_65
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
```

Not sure why it says I am using Java 1.6.

Comment: Look in the Error Log view (or the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory) to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: I think you are running Eclipse under a Java 1.6 while RoboVM requires Java 1.7 or higher. To find out open Eclipse->About Eclipse, click Installation Details and select the Configuration tab. Look for java.version. If it says 1.6 something you're using the wrong JVM.

Comment: So it looks like eclipse is still using Java 1.6. Here are the lines that lead me to believe that : 
eclipse.vmargs=-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 and 
java.version=1.6.0_65. How would I make eclipse use Java 1.7? I followed the instructions here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352715/how-do-i-run-eclipse-using-oracles-new-1-7-jdk-for-the-mac, but Eclipse would not run.